# Jquery Text Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am converting flash banner into html5 banner . Everything is working fine except the text animation. The text should work [like this](http://platform.mediamind.com/Eyeblaster.Preview.Web/Default.aspx?previewID=H56ypDeBz7iKLWoWU5mYSoEvYe1DQb33hNfpQ9%2bTEWE6js1c5xe8aQ==&AdID=20769145&lang=en-US)  but my text is working fine but it is coming over the border it should work like my image animation which is working within the border. Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/tU9LV/

```
<div id = "wrapper" >       
 <div id="mainContainer">

    <div>
 <img id="introImg" src="http://i.imgur.com/FClbHjn.png"/>
    </div>

    <div id="images">
        <p id="headline1Txt" >Striped Bag</p><br />
        <p id="headline2Txt" >$14</p><br />
        <p id="headline3Txt" >Sale $25</p><br />
    </div>
    <div id="ctaBtn">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">SHOP NOW</button>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
     $(document).ready(function () {

bannerAnimation();
    });


function bannerAnimation(){
    //Jquery Animation

    $("#introImg").animate({ width: "120px",
        height: "140px"
    }, 1000);
    $("#headline1Txt").animate({ left: "20" }, 500, function () {
        $("#headline1Txt").animate({ left: "10" }, 200);
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#headline2Txt").animate({ left: "20" }, 500, function () {
            $("#headline3Txt").animate({ left: "20" }, 500, function () {
                $("#headline3Txt").animate({ left: "10" }, 200);
            });
            $("#headline2Txt").animate({ left: "10" }, 200);
        });
    }, 1000);
}* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}



#wrapper {
    outline: 12px solid rgba(186,202,228 , 1);  

    width:285px;
    height:235px;
    position: absolute;

}
#mainContainer{

    background: url('https://secure-ds.serving-sys.com/BurstingRes/Site-8188/Type-0/5fefb401-b187-4d82-b4db-cbd2ef29cc48.gif');
    width:285px;
    height:235px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;



}

#introImg{
    position:absolute;
    top:80px;
    left:150px;
    right:100px;

    opacity: 100;
}



#ctaBtn{
    top:200px;
    left:15px;
    position:absolute;
}

#headline1Txt, #headline2Txt, #headline3Txt
{
      position:absolute;
       overflow: hidden;
    margin:60px 8px;
    left: -120px;



}

#headline2Txt, #headline3Txt
{
       font-size:21px;line-height: 2.0;
}

#headline1Txt
{
      font-size:26px;line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Comment: The border is an image, you have to remove the border from the image, create it as a CSS border, and then have an inner element with overflow hidden to avoid the text showing over the border.

Comment: i dont want to remove the image i have to use the default image

Comment: Border color & text color can be same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution for this if you can't change your background image is to layover a div for the borders..

http://jsfiddle.net/K3SXu/

I've added:

```
<div id="borders"></div>
```

to the html.

and:

```
#borders { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:999; border:12px solid rgba(186,202,228,1); width:285px; height:235px;}
```

to the css. and also removed the 'outline' property from the #wrapper.

it works :)

Comment: thanks Eyal this is great and do you think image animation is fine.

Comment: no problem.. regarding the image animation, I've given you my take on it on a question you've posted about it last week.. I think it looks ok, but to make it even better I'd use a translate animation.. look at what I wrote.

Comment: and one more think i am having problem in my firefox and i dont know it is due to some virus or what jquery is not working properly it is working smoothly in IE but in firefox no script is working

Comment: going to the fiddle link on firefox works fine for me.. maybe you have js disabled for some reason?

Comment: yes i have some problem is it due to virus or what? i had this one in my chrome as well i downloaded firefox but today it is the same problem but everything works fine on IE and my other PC

Comment: Am I not getting it, you accepted this one, but using an overlay makes it impossible to click the button, so this doesn't really work, at least not if a functioning button is what you want ?

Comment: @adeneo you're right, add the property 'pointer-events: none;' to the #borders element

Comment: if you need cross-browser solution refer to this answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements